# Can group have multiple aggregates?

Tags: rethinkdb

I'd like to do something like this:

`r.db('research').table('books').group('year').sum('size_bytes').count().run()`

And get a result like this:

`{
    {"group": 1901,
     "reduction_size_bytes": 13929238,
     "reduction_count": 192},
    {"group": 1902,
     "reduction_size_bytes": 21194721,
     "reduction_count": 223},
    ...
}`

Currently, I only know how to get one "reduction" at a time, e.g. sum of size_bytes:

`r.db('research').table('books').group('year').sum('size_bytes').run()`

Result:

`{
    {"group": 1901,
     "reduction": 13929238},
    {"group": 1902,
     "reduction": 21194721},
    ...
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple aggregations, but you have to manually do it (you can't use sum for example).

This is what you are looking for:

```
r.db('research').table('books').group('year').map(function(book) {
  return {
    size_bytes: book("size_bytes"),
    count: 1
  }
}).reduce(function(left, right) {
  return {
    size_bytes: left("size_bytes").add(right("size_bytes")),
    count: left("count").add(right("count"))
  }
}).run()
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use "add" instead of "+"?

Comment: The `add` operation is executed on the server, and JavaScript doesn't let you overwrite `+` (basically the driver cannot serialize `+` to the function `add` for the server.